# Detecting when model update and send Ajax Request in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application i have model and i want when model update then send an ajax Request to server. for example i have a model like this :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title:DS.attr('string'),
  comment:DS.attr('string')
});
```

And  controllers like this :

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   //if post model update send Ajax Request 
});
App.CommentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  //if post model update send ajax Request
});
App.OtherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 //if post model update send ajax Request
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when model update? When the post object change or when any of its properties change (title, comment) and, how are you setting a model? (Router model hook or something else)

Comment: when model update for example insert,delete or update any record in model i need to send an ajax request to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a action in the route

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions:{
        sendRequest:function(){
            //send Ajax Request
        }
    }
});
```

and in the setupController hook of your post route you subscribe to model events

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    model.on('didUpdate',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
    model.on('didCreate',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
    model.on('didDelete',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
  }
});
```

hope this help, it's only an example, you can do it in several ways, the idea is to subscribe to model events that fire when the server respond to POST, PUT or DELETE requests

based on your JsBin....

```
OlapApp.OlapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller,model){
    var that = this;
      this.store.findAll('axisModel').then(function(axisModel){
        axisModel.on('didUpdate',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
        axisModel.on('didCreate',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
        axisModel.on('didDelete',controller,function(){this.send('sendRequest')})
        that.controllerFor('OlapColumn').set('model', axisModel);
        that.controllerFor('OlapRow').set('model', axisModel);
        that.controllerFor('OlapFilter').set('model', axisModel);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: when i try using your way i get this `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method on` error.in comment route how can i find when Post Model change ?thanks

Comment: What is the result of a `console.log(model)`?

Comment: my real controller is like this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/efAfUvA/1/edit?js). i have axisModel and some controller use this model and can update know i want when model update i can sed a request. i you say why i use this way because im using renderTemplate in my router.

Comment: for log of model in console it say `undefined` and i think its true because OlapRoute havent any model its only set model for other controllers